# seaborn plot violin of the arrays

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn, data-visualization, violin-plot

I have two arrays:

```
l1 = [2,1,5,6,1,2,4,5,6,1]

l2 = [7,8,4,1,3,4,8]
```

I want to plot a seaborn violinplot with different color per list (a separate violin for l1 and l2).
Is there a way to do so without creating a dataframe and pd.melt from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the parameters to `sns.violinplot()` without provding a dataframe, as follows:

```py
import seaborn as sns

l1 = [2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4]
l2 = [7, 8, 4, 1, 3, 4, 8]
flag = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
sns.violinplot(y=l1 + l2, x=["l1"]*len(l1) + ["l2"]*len(l2),
               hue=flag + flag, palette=['crimson', 'cornflowerblue'])
```

[image: violinplot for two arrays]

To only use the l1 vs l2 information:

```
import seaborn as sns

l1 = [2, 1, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4]
l2 = [7, 8, 4, 1, 3, 4, 8]
sns.violinplot(y=l1 + l2, x=["l1"] * len(l1) + ["l2"] * len(l2), palette=['tomato', 'cornflowerblue'])
```

[image: sns.violinplot from two lists]

Comment: I meant that x Axis is flag (0 or 1) and y is the distribution, is this possible?

Comment: So, you wouldn't really use `l1` vs `l2`? Something like `sns.violinplot(y=l1 + l2, x=flag+flag, hue=flag+flag)`?

Comment: Sorry I had a misunderstanding, please see the edit - no need for flag?